# QTP dynamic Links

Tags: qtp

I have a webtable and there are many dynamic links.I need to click on a particular link which I have already selected from the weblist. I tried few codes but they are not working please give me some valuable solution.

```
Scheme = DataTable.Value("Scheme", "dtDataSheet")

If checkIfItemExistInWeblist(sScheme, Browser("ViewPortfolio").Page("AddTransaction").WebList("schemeId") Then
    Browser("View Portfolio").Page("Add Transaction").WebList("schemeId").Select sScheme
    Wait(5)
    sSchemeName = sScheme
End If

goToSchemePage(sSchemeName)

Function goToSchemePage(sSchemeName)    
    Dim oAnchor
    Dim blnFound
    Set oAnchors = Browser("AssetDetails").Page("AssetDetails").WebElement("SchemeLastNAVUnits/Avg.").Object.GetElementsByTagName("A") 

    blnFound = False
    For Each oAnchor in oAnchors
        If oAnchor.innertext = sSchemeName Then
            oAnchor.Click()
            blnFound = True
        End If
        Set oAnchor = Nothing

        If blnFound = True Then Exit For
    Next 'oAnchor

    Set oAnchors = Nothing
End Function
```

But it's not working please provide me your valuable solution.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your HTML document structure, nobody can help you. A good idea might be to create a dump script that dumps the table´s structure as seen by the WebTable API. Or, alternatively, singlestep the script shown, inspecting SetoAnchors etc. as they are set.

Comment: What's not working, exactly? Are you getting an error message? Does it just run to the end without finding a matching A?